# Ember acceptance test not seeing updated DOM

Tags: ember.js, acceptance-testing

I'm still getting into the depths of Ember's acceptance testing. One issue I seem to keep having is the DOM not getting updated after an event. For example, my page has a side menu. A simple toggle changes a property in it's component which then toggles a "hide" class on the menu itself:

**Component**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  menuHidden: true,
  actions: {
    toggleMenu(){
      this.set('menuHidden', !this.get('menuHidden'));
    },
  }
});
```

**Template**

```
<a id="menu-toggle" class="{{unless menuHidden 'open'}}" {{ action 'toggleMenu' }}>
  <span></span><span></span><span></span>
</a>
<div id="menu" class="{{if menuHidden 'hide'}}">
  {{#link-to 'dashboard' invokeAction='closeMenu'}}Dashboard{{/link-to}}
  {{#each menu as |child|}}
    {{menu-child child=child createCase=(action 'createCase') menuHidden=menuHidden}}
  {{/each}}
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" {{ action 'logout' }}>Logout</a>
</div>
```

**Acceptance Test**

```
import { test } from 'ember-qunit';
import moduleForAcceptance from '../helpers/module-for-acceptance';

moduleForAcceptance('Acceptance | side menu');

test('side menu opens and closes', assert=>{

  logIn('my@email.com', 'password');

  andThen(()=>{
    assert.equal(find('#menu').attr('class'), 'hide', 'Hidden by default');

    click('#menu-toggle');

    andThen(()=>{
      assert.equal(find('#menu').attr('class'), '', 'Now visible');
    });
  });

});
```

Now this is running fine in the browser. The test is logging in fine with my custom helper (the menu is only visible when logged in) and if I drop a `console.log` into `toggleMenu()` it is being triggered by the test. But it fails the last `assert`. I've done a console.log on the menu's wrapper's HTML before the last `assert`, it's still seeing the `#menu` element with `class=hide`

Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong? I can't find many examples of people with multiple `andThen` calls in acceptance tests, so I've tried having it nested - as above - and pulling the second `andThen` out inline with the first one. No difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the developer console in the test browser window, you will likely see this error:

```
Assertion failed: You have turned on testing mode, which disabled the run-loop's autorun. You will need to wrap any code with asynchronous side-effects in an Ember.run
```

The following line in your component is considered code with asynchronous side-effects:

```
this.set('menuHidden', !this.get('menuHidden'));
```

Instead, for the test to work, you need to manually add the line to the run-loop, which is achieved by adding that line of code in an `Ember.run`, like so:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  menuHidden: true,
  actions: {
    toggleMenu(){
      Ember.run(this, function(){
        this.set('menuHidden', !this.get('menuHidden'));
      });
    },
  }
});
```

This will not affect the actual running code as the operations in your `Ember.run` will get merged into the main run-loop.

I had a similar issue which I managed to resolve after going through the steps mentioned in [here](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/guide-asynchronous-side-effects-in-testing/2905)